# How to create an All-Day event in SharePoint Online Calendar using Power Automate flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, power-automate, calendar, events

I have a pretty basic flow that successfully creates a Calendar entry in a SharePoint online calendar.  I had to write an expression for the Start and End dates because it was being created a day earlier.  So I'm good there.  But my new requirement here is to now have the flow create All-Day events.  How can I use my Power Automate flow to also check this box on each New item?

[image]

My flow (when a new item is created, it starts an approval.  When the approval response = Approve, it sends an email and creates the calendar item:
[image]

I haven't found a clear answer other than using Send http request to SharePoint action, but I'm not all that clear on how to set that up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add screenshot of your current flow? M

Comment: I just added a screen shot of my flow.  When a new item is created, an approval starts.  Then a condition that says if the response = Approve, send an email and create the calendar item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example flow for you:

[image]

Headers

```
{    
  "Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata",    
  "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=nometadata"    
}
```

---

```
Body
{
"Title": "All Day Event",
"EventDate": "2024-03-05T12:00:00Z",
"EndDate": "2024-03-05T12:00:00Z",
"fAllDayEvent": true
}
```

[image]